# Memoizing a dynamic styled-component causes "Rendered fewer hooks than expected error."

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components, kendo-react-ui

I'm using styled-components. I have to use it to make the style changes because what I need to change is nested inside Kendo React Grid, as they outline in their docs: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/styling/styled-components/

I need to style the component dynamically based on props. The problem this creates is that, because a new component is created every render cycle, text inputs lose focus as you type. I tried to wrap the component in useMemo to solve this, but it causes a "Rendered fewer hooks than expected" error. It seems useRef is being called in styled() from styled-components, so when it subsequently is skipped because of useMemo, it creates the hooks mismatch.

I created a simpler example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mu6rlr-omeo5c?file=app%2Fmain.jsx

```
function CustomText(props){
  const [state, setState] = useState('text')
  const {color} = props

  const Input = styled('input')`
    background-color: ${color}
  `

  return <Input value={state} onChange={useCallback(event => setState(event.target.value))}/>
}
// loses focus on update


function CustomTextMemo(props){
  const [state, setState] = useState('memoized')
  const {color} = props

  const Input = useMemo(
    () => styled('input')`
      background-color: ${color}
    `,
    [color]
  )

  return <Input value={state} onChange={useCallback(event => setState(event.target.value))}/>
}
// "Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement."
```

The top text box loses focus on update. The lower memoized one hits the hook error.

What is a better pattern for solving this?

Comment: is it meant to be   const {color} = props.color?

Also, i have solved this problem before but cannot recall how i did it. Can you add in more information such as what was before the function CustomText(props){

Comment: It's an anti-pattern defining it within a functional component. Instead, it should be defined outside of a component (or in its own file) and passed props. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56047659/multiple-props-options-for-styled-components/56049471#56049471) shows how to pass props and set dynamic styles based upon them. In your case, pass props to `Input` like so: `<Input color={color} onChange{...} value={...}/>`, then you can access `color` within the styled-component template literal: `background: ${({ color }) => color };`.

Comment: Excellent, I knew I must have been missing something in styled-components. Thank you. I updated the example with the proper implementation. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mu6rlr-omeo5c?file=app%2Fmain.jsx @MattCarlotta

Comment: @MattCarlotta there are times when there are props to pass in so many places that it really would be nicer to have the styled components capture the context. I tried useMemo and got this same problem. I understand that you're supposed to define them outside, but is there a way around it for cases where it's too messy to pass all the props?

Comment: @JonathanTuzman Have you tried using [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)? If not, that's the better approach. Otherwise, you can use styled-components [theming](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Matt Carlotta pointed out in his comment, I was using an anti-pattern by defining the styled-component within the functional component. I thought it was necessary to define it where props were in scope in order to use props for the styling. What I'd missed in styled-components is that you can define the styles as functions of props, and it will behave as expected. I updated the example with the correct implementation.

stackblitz.com/edit/react-mu6rlr-omeo5c?file=app%2Fmain.jsx