# How to pass styles from a child to the parent using styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

I am trying to create a few variants of buttons and decided to use Styled Components to accomplish this. However, I am having some issues trying to pass a variant button from a child to the parent that holds all the variants.

Currently, I have a Navbar that imports the Button.js component. I would like to have the option to change the button within the Navbar.js like this:

```js
<Button default label="Game" />
<Button secondary label="Dictionary" />
```

However, within my Button.js file, I have tried switching the style of the button through using props, but this does not work.

```js
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const ButtonStyle = styled.span`
  // shared styles ...
  // props
  background: ${props => props.primary ? "red" : "white"};

`

function Button({ label }) {
  return <ButtonStyle>{label}</ButtonStyle>
}

export default Button
```

I've also tried extending styles, but the problem is that the name, TomatoeButton, does not get passed to the Navbar.js component.

```js
const TomatoButton = styled(Button)`
  color: tomato;
  border-color: tomato;
`;
```

Shouldn't this take in the primary attribute and change the color of the background?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the above is that `Button` must accept a `className` prop from `styled(Button)`. Then it needs to pass it down to `StyledButton`:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const ButtonStyle = styled.span`
  // shared styles ...
  // props
  background: ${props => props.primary ? "red" : "white"};
`

export function Button({ className, label }) {
  return <ButtonStyle className={className}>{label}</ButtonStyle>
}

const TomatoButton = styled(Button)`
  color: tomato;
  border-color: tomato;
`;

export default TomatoButton;
```

Styled-components works by assigning a unique `className` to the element. If you're using `styled.HTMLElement` (styled.div, styled.img, ..etc), then it does it automatically. However, when you wrap a React component with styled, then it assumes that it'll accept and manually assign the className to the component.

For example:

```
import * as React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components"

// the result of "RedButton" is <button className="sc-hBEYos dWjUC">{children}</button>
const RedButton = styled.button`
  color: red;
`; 

// the result of "Example" is <button className="sc-hBEYos dWjUC">Test</button>
const Example = () => <RedButton>Test</RedButton>
```

When you're using a React component, then it must accept and assign the `className` and `children` (and possibly other incoming props) and assign them manually:

```
import * as React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

// the result of "Button" is <button className={className}>{children}</button>
const Button = ({ className, children }) => (
  <button className={className}>
    {children}
  </button>
);

// the result of "BlueButton" is <button className="sc-hBEYos dWjUC">{children}</button>
const BlueButton = styled(Button)`
  color: blue;
`;

// the result of "Example2" is <button className="sc-hBEYos dWjUC">Test</button>
const ExampleTwo = () => <BlueButton>Test</BlueButton>
```

As you can see, styling composed React components can get a bit redundant and verbose if you try wrapping them with other styled components (you have to keep passing down `className`), so instead I'd recommend using the [Referring to other components](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components) approach.

In short, keep the styled-components as `styled.HTMLElement` and if you need to wrap them, then use the composing (referring to other components) method mentioned above:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Button = styled.button`
  color: red;
`;

const BlackBlueButton = styled.div`
  background: black;

  ${Button} {
    color: blue;
  }
`;

// In short, the result is that the "Button" below gets two classNames, one from 
// itself (styled.button) and another from "BlackBlueButton".
const Example = () => (
  <BlackBlueButton>
    <Button>Test</Button>
  </BlackBlueButton>
);
```

On a separate note, if you're trying to create flexible components, then take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56047659/multiple-props-options-for-styled-components/56049471#56049471).

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I was trying to look for a solution that made it simple to set an indicator on a button, such as primary, and have that get passed to the button component to determine the specific styling.